# Show slide before first animation in slide zoom preview image

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide with an image and a few annotations to that image. I want to zoom to this slide from an overview slide. On the overview slide, I don't want the annotations to show yet, so I added animations to the annotation text and arrows. When I start the presentation on the detail slide, this works as expected: At first, only the image is shown, and then the annotations fade in.

However, I don't get the expected result with the zoom: On the overview slide, the detail slide preview already includes the annotations. When I click on the preview, the annotations disappear during the zoom and reappear shortly after. This is not what I want. I want the preview to show the detail slide in the state before the first animation. Is this possible?

I know that I can create a copy of my detail slide and delete everything that shall appear later - but I was wondering if there is a more convenient way...

Comment: Rather than using a second slide use an image of your slide as you want to be shown before being zoomed and use that one in the overview slide.

Comment: @MoisesNajar, this is indeed another option, but it suffers from the same drawbacks as the second slide solution: If I change the slide, I also need to redundantly update the image used for the zoom.

Comment: What I regularly do is to use an image related to the theme as an Intro instead of showing the miniature of the slide e.g. a meeting for themes related to some office issues, a graphic to explain results and so on, unfortunately for your requirements I'd do the same that you're doing, If somebody suggest a solution, that will be good to know.